# Quando acentuar verbos com pronomes enclíticos?

Tags: gramática, verbos, pronomes

Qual a correta utilização do acento na última sílaba do verbo antes do hífen?

Por exemplo, existe alguma regra que determina se é **buscá-lo** ou **busca-lo**? **Destruí-lo** ou **destrui-lo**?

Comment: Quer dizer  "implícitos", não? Se o sujeito for _eu_, i.e. primeira pessoa, a forma correcta é _buscá-lo/la_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para acentuar verbos com pronomes enclíticos, usa-se a mesma regra geral de acentuação que se aplica a todas as palavras em português. Mas, dado que todos os verbos no infinitivo em português terminam em "r" e, ao adicionar o pronome, esse "r" é removido, restam apenas oxítonas terminadas em "a", "e", "i" ou "o".

De acordo com a regra geral, oxítonas terminadas em "a", "e" e "o" são todas acentuadas. No caso das terminadas em "i", se a última sílaba é composta apenas do "i" (ex.: **des-tru-í**-lo), ele receberá acento. Nos demais casos (ex.: **par-ti**-lo), a última sílaba não é acentuada.

Comment: Muito bom, Otávio! Sintético, objetivo! Valeu!