# verbo + ‘me’, ‘te’, ‘lhe’, etc. + ‘o’, ‘lo’, etc

Tags: gramática, verbos, pronomes-oblíquos

Bem, gostaria de obter uma resposta estruturada que explicasse qual o uso correcto em todas as variantes de

> verbo + *me, te, lhe*, etc + *o, lo*, etc.

Não sei a terminologia, portanto, passo a exemplificar:

> «Não fui eu que mos dei» ou «Não fui eu que me los dei»?
>
> «Deste-mos?» ou «Deste-me-los?» ?

Neste momento, não me lembro de mais exemplos com outros verbos, ou com 'apêndices' diferentes de *me* ou *los*.

Qualquer ajuda seria muito bem vinda.

Comment: Para sua informação, se escrever, no campo Infinitivo de [LX Conjugator](http://lxcenter.di.fc.ul.pt/services/pt/LXServicesConjugatorPT.html) da U. de Lisboa, **dar**; e escolher (a) em opções para conjugação pronominal, ditransitivo [Suj V Cdir Cind]; (b) em clítico, não reflexivo dativo, pessoa 1, número S, (**me**); (c) outro clítico, não reflexivo acusativo, pessoa 3, número P, Género M (**os**), obtém a conjugação de **dar-mos**. Vê-se que o pretérito perfeito simples se conjuga eu dei-mos, tu **deste-mos**, ele/ela/você deu-mos, nós demos-mos, vós destes-mos, eles/elas/vocês deram-mos.

Comment: @AméricoTavares Esse conjugador é muito interessante. Agora, quando eu seleciono «ditransitivo» e o dativo «lhes», ele já não me deixa escolher um acusativo. Aparentemente não reconhece a contração *lhes+o* = *lho*. A mim também me sou estranha, mas está no Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra.

Comment: @Jacinto o **lho** aparece com as escolhas `ditransitivo` + **lhe** em `não reflexo dativo` (pessoa=3, número=S) + **o** em `não reflexo dativo` (pessoa=3, número=S, género=M).

Comment: @AméricoTavares Sim, sim, eu experimentei essas combinações. Com ***lhes*** é já não permite juntar o acusativo.

Comment: @Jacinto Ah, com **lhes**, não tinha percebido!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A tua pergunta é sobre ***combinações e contrações de pronomes átonos***. Os pronomes ***me, te, lhe, lhes, nos*** e ***vos*** na função de objeto indireto combinam-se com os pronomes ***o, a, os, as*** (objeto direto) da seguinte forma:

**1.** ***me, te, lhe*** e ***lhes*** contraem-se com ***o, a, as***: ***mo, to, lho*** e do mesmo modo com *a, as* e *os*:

> Ana: O João tem o teu livro.
> Eu: Não, ele deu-***mo*** esta manhã / já ***mo*** deu esta manhã.
>
> Ana: Quero os meus livros de volta.
> Bela: Disparate, eu dei-***tos*** ontem / já ***tos*** dei ontem.
>
> Pedro: A Ana precisa que ***lhe*** devolvas a mala dela.
> Bela: Devolvi-***lha*** ontem / já ***lha*** devolvi.
>
> Pedro: A Ana e o João precisam que ***lhes*** devolvas a mala deles.
> Bela: Devolvi-***lha*** ontem / já ***lha*** devolvi ontem.

Nota que ***lhes*** perde o ***s*** na contração, pelo que na forma contraída não se distingue o ***lhe*** do ***lhes***. Isto é uma herança do português antigo, em que ***lhe*** era invariável, tal com *seu, sua*, que tanto se refere a uma pessoa como a várias.

**2.** ***nos*** e ***vos*** perdem o ***s*** e ligam-se com hífen: ***no-lo, vo-la*** e plurais. Os pronomes *o, a, os, as* ganham um ***l***. No fundo comportam-se como quando se ligam diretamente a verbos sem interposição doutro pronome: *dou o livro → dou-o*; *damos o livro → damo-lo*.

> O João tem o vosso livro.
> Nós: Não, ele deu-***no-lo*** esta manhã / já ***no-lo*** deu esta manhã.
>
> João e Maria: Precisamos da nossa mala.
> Bela: Mas eu dei-***vo-la*** ontem / já ***vo-la*** dei ontem.

Esta combinações e contrações são comuns no português europeu, mas raras no português brasileiro contemporâneo, segundo Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (*Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo*, Lisboa, 2014, p. 391).

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. Em qualquer forma verbal que acabe em ***s, z*** ou ***r***, tiras a consoante e juntas ***lo, la, los, las***: *tu conhece-lo, ele fá-lo, e preciso fazê-lo*. Mas isto já é outra pergunta.

Comment: Muito obrigado ;)

Comment: Jacinto e @Anoldmaninthesea. se é outra pergunta aproveitem para fazer que temos poucas no site.

Comment: @JorgeB. Já existe [esta pergunta relacionada](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/99/quando-acentuar-verbos-com-pronomes-encl%C3%ADticos), mas parece-me diferente.

Comment: Sempre me pareceu muito curioso o facto do que o português não tem a combinação *se* + *o/a/os/as* (e dali *so/sa/sos/sas*), apesar de ser uma combinação frequente em línguas irmãs.

Comment: @Guifa Podes dar exemplos? Esse ***se*** é o pronome indefinido?

Comment: @Jacinto vamos a dizer que acabo de mandar um livro a alguém. Digo *mandei-lho (a ele)*. Mesmo se a sua namorada lhe mandasse: *mandou-lho*. Mas se fosse ele mesmo que mandou o livro para si mesmo (por exemplo, quando de férias no estrangeiro para a sua casa), não é possível no português dizer *mandou-se-o/mandou-so*, mas no asturiano temos *unvióselu* ou castelhano *mandóselo* (porque nestas o *se* reflexivo pode exercer a função tanto direta como indireta)

Comment: @Jacinto essa pergunta não tem nada a ver. Se quiserem criar outra...

Comment: No Brasil, só ouvi "lho" e mais raramente "mo", mas mais como "lh'o" e "m'o". Isto em frases mais informais.

Comment: @Schilive, *lh'o* e *m'o* era como se escrevia antigamente. Mas tu dizes "ouvi"... como é que tu ouves a diferença?

Comment: @Jacinto, pelo menos no Brasil, as pessoas não tentam dizer “de o” e sai “d'o”, mas elas dizem apenas “do”. Quando ouvi alguém dizer “dou-lho”, tentava dizer “dou-lhe-o” e saiu “dou-lh'o”, assim como em “ele salt'e salta pela rua”. Eu sei disso porque essa pessoa diz *lh'* amiúde, como em “dou-lh' uma porrada nas fuças!”