# Verbo+"se"+pronome acusativo: por exemplo, "vê-se-o" ou "vê-se-lo"?

Tags: gramática

No seguimento [desta questão](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3583/verbo-me-te-lhe-etc-o-lo-etc), como conjugaríamos pronominalmente um verbo+se+o/a/os/as?

Por exemplo, *vê-se-o* ou *vê-se-lo*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [verbo + ‘me’, ‘te’, ‘lhe’, etc. + ‘o’, ‘lo’, etc](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3583/verbo-me-te-lhe-etc-o-lo-etc)

Comment: Peixoto, não penso que seja uma duplicação, uma vez que a questão anterior apenas aborda me,te,lhe,nos,vos,lhes.  Aliás, num dos comentários dessa questão é sugerido precisamente isso, que se abra uma nova, para que se possa responder a este ponto. Por esta razão, e depois de não ter encontrado qualquer outra igual, decidi colocar esta.

Comment: Você poderia me dar uma frase de exemplo? Não creio que seja possível isso.

Answer (score 6):

A forma possível é ***vê-se-o***. Não acabando *se* em *s*, *z*, ou *r*, não se usará a forma *lo*.

No entanto, a combinação *se* + acusativo não é aceita na língua padrão. É considerada dialetal. Diz Ana Maria Martirns no cap. 42 da *Gramática do Português* editada pela Gulbenkian (pág. 2235):

> Não é [...] permitida a formação de um grupo clítico constituído por *se* + acusativo, como mostra a impossibilidade de frases como: **pinta-se-a de azul*, **ouve-se-os gritar o tempo todo*, **cura-se-te banhos de mar*, **penteia-se-te com tranças*, **engana-se-vos facilmente* [nota de rodapé: Existem, no entanto, dialetos portugueses (merdidionais e insulares) que permitem que se combinem num grupo clítico *se* e um pronome acusativo da terceira pessoa. Os exemplos a seguir apontados foram extraídos do _Corpus Dialectal para o Estudo da Sintaxe (CORDIAL-SIN):
>
> - Em sendo para a latada, *deixa-se-a* crescer (Porto Santo, Madeira)
> - *Pode-se-a* guardar na 'freeze' e comer daqui a dois ou três meses (Santo Espírito, Santa Maria, Açores)
> - *Abre-se-o* de um metro de fundura e um metro de largura (Alcochete, Setúbal)
> - Mas *carregava-se-o* aí às vezes também nos carros de bestas e em coisas. (Melides, Setúbal).
>     ]

Repara que em todos estes exemplos podemos considerar estar perante o *se* nominativo (construção impessoal). Não vamos encontrar um *se* anticausativo (como em *o barco virou-se*), porque aí o verbo perde a transitividade. E geralmente não é difícil encontrar alternativas à combinação *se* impessoal + acusativo:

- Com verbos perceptivos (como *ver*) ou causativos como *fazer*, *deixar* ou *mandar*, pode usar-se antes uma construção com infinitivo pessoal: *ouve-se eles gritarem o tempo todo*, *em sendo para a latada, deixa-se ela crescer*.
- Quando há uma construção que permite subida de clítico, pode deixar-se *se* no verbo finito e passar o clítico acusativo para o verbo no infinitivo: *Pode-se guardá-la na 'freeze' e comer daqui a dois ou três meses.*
- Substituir *se* por *uma pessoa*: *mas uma pessoa carregava-o aí às vezes nos carros de bestas e em coisas*.
- Usar uma construção passiva com *se*, mas eliminando o clítico acusativo e passando o verbo para o plural, se necessário. **Não gostamos das paredes, mas pinta-se-as de azul e ficam bem* -> *Não gostamos das paredes, mas pintam-se de azul e ficam bem*.
- Usar uma construção passiva com *ser*: *Em sendo para a latada, (ela) é deixada crescer*.

Answer (score 0):

Uma vez que o pronome não é precedido de consoante, não há motivo nenhum para haver um "l". Portanto: vê-se-o.