# “Tomar-no-lo-ão” é tecnicamente possível na língua portuguesa?

Tags: pronomes, colocação-pronominal, pronomes-oblíquos

Eu sei que não usamos mais combinações de pronomes (*mo, lho, to, no-lo, vo-lo*), mas se ainda usássemos, seria possível esse uso da mesóclise com o pronome combinado *no-lo* ou existe alguma regra que impede isso?
Por exemplo:
*Eles tomarão o carro de nós* se torna:
*Tomar-no-lo-ão eles.*

Comment: Nos quem? Os portugueses continuam usando esses pronomes. Eles tomarão o carro de nós. é registro baixo. tomar em que sentido? Eles levarão o nosso carro, por exemplo.

Comment: O sentido de tomar não é relevante para a compreensão da pergunta, tanto que nem eu me mesmo me preocupei com ele. Com “nós” refiro-me a nós brasileiros, já que no Brasil não se usa mais a mesóclise popularmente; não fazia ideia que em Portugal se usava, mas de novo, não é relevante para a compreensão da pergunta, então não importa muito.

Comment: Sim, é melhor indicar o país porque aqui há muitos portugueses que participam. Acho que sim, tomar é importante para a pregunta. Por exemplo, a mesóclise é norma cultura, tomar o carro de nós, não. E os portugueses na fala usam os alguns dos outros.

Comment: @Lambie Tenho certeza que todos, até os portugueses, entendem que “tomar” é um verbo e que “tomar-no-lo-ão” é uma mesóclise desse mesmo verbo no futuro do presente e isso basta para entenderem o fundamento da minha pergunta. Não vejo necessidade em indicar o país, uma vez que é fácil ver que a pergunta não depende do regionalismo para ser compreendida, ou seja, não importa se a mesóclise é usada ou não aqui ou ali. Se você sabe o que é mesóclise, então você consegue responder a pergunta, se não sabe, não tem porque se incomodar e nem a mais ninguém.

Comment: Desculpa, mas quando se faz uma pergunta, o registro tem importância. O problema não é o verbo tomar, e o "tomar de nós" que nunca apareceria numa mesóclise que é por definição norma culta. Em vez de me dizer que incomodo, deveria me agradecer o conhecimento. E se não me acredita, pergunta ao Jacinto. Falei aqui em país, porque ele é português, e sabe mais sobre tudo isso que qualquer outro participante.

Comment: Eu, de fato, agradeço pelo conhecimento, mas ainda não entendo como tudo isso importa. A pergunta é clara de um jeito ou de outro e eu fui respondido; não vejo isso como de muito relevância. Não tive a intenção de te ofender nem de dizer que está me incomodando e peço perdão pelo mal entendido, contudo, já estou cansado de digitar, então pretendo parar de responder. Tenha uma boa tarde!

Answer (score 8):

Esta construção está atestada desde os primórdios da literatura em português, mas vai rareando hoje em dia. Exemplo de [Ramalho Ortigão (1836 – 1915)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=v3DRAAAAMAAJ&q=%22vo-lo-%C3%A3o%22&dq=%22vo-lo-%C3%A3o%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiKieuhm4f1AhWQ3oUKHVlbA-UQ6AF6BAgDEAI), citado por Manuel da Cruz Malpique (negrito meu em todas as citações):

> Sede sátiros apenas, se o puderdes ser com a hipocrisia devida à morigeração das aparências.
> Satíricos nunca! As classes médias não **vo-lo levarão** a bem; as classe baixas **levar-vo-lo-ão** a mal

De outros grandes autores, temos ***far-no-lo-ão*** de [Oliveira Marques (1988)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=-i5xAAAAMAAJ&q=%22no-lo-%C3%A3o%22&dq=%22no-lo-%C3%A3o%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjG5-6o54b1AhWD3YUKHbklAmUQ6AF6BAgFEAI), ***dir-vo-lo-ei*** de [Alexandre Herculano (1843)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=9uC5B6Za6UsC&pg=PA13&dq=%22vo-lo-hei%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRo_2RvYn1AhXKyYUKHSbcBGwQ6AF6BAgQEAI#v=onepage&q=%22vo-lo-hei%22&f=false), ***dar-vo-lo-ei*** de [Almeida Garret (1842)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=SUJEAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA106&lpg=PA106&dq=%22dar-vo-lo-hei%22&source=bl&ots=T18HNOt6d1&sig=ACfU3U1sTsFoUknf2RjUPWf2KlaOsOXcIg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjVlZyv04n1AhVEx4UKHaaVCogQ6AF6BAgtEAM#v=onepage&q=%22dar-vo-lo-hei%22&f=false). E não poderíamos saltar [Luís de Camões (*Filodemo*, ato 2, cena 2; edição de 1834)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=M9YQAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA409&dq=%22vo-lo-hei%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiBpPm2wYn1AhWLzIUKHbb-AUo4KBDoAXoECA0QAg#v=onepage&q=%22vo-lo-hei%22&f=false)

> […] o caso he este; **dir-vo-lo-hei**; porém he necessário que primeiro vos alimpeis como marmelo, e que ajunteis para hum canto da casa todos esses maos pensamentos;

Depois temos ***agradecer-vo-lo-emos*** em [carta do rei D. João II a Cristóvão Colombo (1488)](http://ph-colombina.blogspot.com/2006/12/carta-de-1488-de-d-joo-ii-cristvo.html), e termino com um [cantiga de amigo do século XIII](https://cantigas.fcsh.unl.pt/cantiga.asp?cdcant=669&pv=sim) (clica nos quadradinhos à esquerda para notas explicativas):

> —Dizede-m’ora filha, por Santa Maria
> […]
> Qual est o voss’amigo que mi vos pedia?
> Se mi o vós mostrássedes, **gracir-vo-lo-ia**. [= *agradecer-vo-lo-ia*]
> —Madr’, eu **amostrar-vo-lo-ei**

A propósito de *far-vo-la-ei* , diz o [Ciberdúvidas (2008)](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/far-vo-la-ei/22418) que “é uma combinatória possível, mas complexa e rara”. [Jorge Madeira Mendes (*A folha, boletim da língua portuguesa nas instituições europeias*, 2015)](https://ec.europa.eu/translation/portuguese/magazine/documents/folha49_pt.pdf), observa que formas como *ter-vo-lo-emos* e *ter-vo-lo-íamos* são gramaticais mas que há uma tendência incipiente já avalizada por alguns gramáticos jovens para substituir a mesóclise pela ênclise, resultando em coisas como *teremo-las* ou  *teríamo-las*. O meu Word assinala erro nestas ênclises, mas não nos *ter-vo-lo-ia, far-no-lo-ão*, etc.

---

**Observações:**

As combinações *mo, to, lho, no-la*, etc. já não se usam no Brasil, mas usam-se em Portugal. Vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3583/verbo-me-te-lhe-etc-o-lo-etc). O *no-lo* e *vo-lo* são raros na linguagem coloquial, mas *mo, to, lho*, etc. são relativamente comuns. A mesóclise é que é também relativamente rara na linguagem coloquial. Contribuem para isso a tendência a substituir o futuro por outros tempos (eu normalmente não digo *o livro? levar-to-ei amanhã*; digo antes *levo-to amanhã* ou *vou levar-to amanhã*) e a substituir o condicional/futuro do pretérito pelo imperfeito do indicativo (*se pudesse, ajudava-te* em vez de *ajudar-te-ia*).

Comment: Muito grato, amigo! Esclareceu-me muito.

Comment: @єυlєтяicσ, com a tua correção, eliminei uma observação que agora seria inútil.

Comment: Sim, Jacinto, sim, só que""tomar o carro de nós" não é registro alto. E a mesóclise em todo caso é um uso de norma culta, se não me engano. Acho importante falar nisso/disso.

Comment: @Lambie o que queres dizer com registro alto?

Comment: @FabricioG Norma culta.

Comment: @Jacinto as combinações pronominais "mo, to e lho" são mesmo usadas em Portugal? estou aqui há 6 meses e ainda não me deparei com ninguém que as usou.

Comment: @FabricioG, são pois. Se calhar não prestaste atenção. Se procurares na net encontras facilmente: [trotinete ... e já lha demos](https://demaeparamae.pt/forum/brinquedos-2-anos); ou [medicação ... já lha receitaram](https://www.dodot.pt/bebe/desenvolvimento/artigo/bronquiolite-e-bronquite-viral-em-criancas)

Answer (score 2):

Existem outras formas também que são admissíveis de acordo com a '(Gramática do Português, Fundação Calouste Gulbenkian, vol. II, pág. 2235).'

Construções como **se-mo(a), se-lho(a), se-vo-lo(a), se-no-lo(a)**.

Exemplos: «Sobre as provas... **apresentar-se-vo-las-ão** amanhã». Ou seja, **apresentar-se-ão** as provas a vós. Fica mais compacto do que dizer a frase extensa.

Outro exemplo: «Quanto aos chocolates **trar-se-mo-ão** ainda hoje?» (**trar-se-ão** para mim os chocolates?).

O exemplo com mais hífens que encontrei é com o verbo **«pré-abrir-se».**

Ex: «Aos alunos que farão a prova do ENEM: as portas **pré-abrir-se-vo-las-ão** ao meio-dia». (**pré-abrir-se-ão** as portas a vós).

Outra coisa: **vo-lo(a)(s), no-lo(a)(s)** podem iniciar frases e parágrafos.

Ex.: «**No-lo** dirão amanhã, sabes? — perguntava à sua mãe». Ou, **dir-no-lo-ão**, como se queira preferir.

Além disso, existem as formas «enclíticas compostas» (**fora-se-me, diga-se-lhe, conto-vo-lo,trouxemo-vo-las, trazíei-vo-las, fizeste-vo-los, entregastes-no-las**,...).

Infelizmente a norma padrão não admite as formas **«se-o»** como existe amplamente em espanhol. Como: **«faz-se-o»**, **«traz-se-a»**, **dizer-se-os** etc. Em espanhol o uso é assaz frequente: **decírselo, traersela, hacerselos**...

Espero ter-te ajudado!

Bem-hajas!

Comment: Excelente. Obrigado por esta primeira contribuição — espero que possamos contar com muitas outras.

Comment: Várias coisas a melhorar nesta resposta. a começar por coisas erradas: "no-lo dirão" não é possível porque não há contexto para proclise (65.1.3 na gramática da Gulbenkian), assim como "troxuxemo-vo-las" e "trazíei-vo-las" (o s só cai com verbo e na 1.a pessoa pl e com "nos"). E no ex. dos chocolates (plural) devia estar "mos". De resto, arriscaria que os exemplos dados não seriam escritos e muito menos ditos por nenhum falante da língua (são super estranhos, contrariamente  aos do Jacinto), e que seria melhor substituí-los por exemplos da literatura.