No português, existe uma forma de substituir objetos diretos e indiretos do mesmo verbo?
Peço desculpas de antemão se a minha pergunta for um pouco imprecisa.
Em espanhol, uma construção muito comum consiste em usar um verbo transitivo direto e indireto, juntamente a dois pronomes. Por exemplo “Juan me lo dijo” - “Juan disse isso para mim”.
Uma construção similar existe em francês, como por exemplo “Je le lui dis” - “Eu digo isso a ele”.
Minha pergunta é:

Existe este tipo de construção em português?

Pessoalmente, nunca me deparei com nenhuma instância - minha tendência é de ou suprimir um dos pronomes (se a informação está clara pelo contexto) ou evitar um dos pronomes e usar o objeto sem substituí-lo. Ademais, se existe, gostaria de uma referência para aprender a usá-la; em particular, qual a ordem que os pronomes devem seguir?
Obrigado desde já!

https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/pronominalizacao-e-contraccao-de-pronomes/28391

Sim! E são formas contraídas:
Por exemplo:

"Eu disse isso a ele"

Torna-se:

"Eu disse-lho /"eu lho disse"

Outras formas são:

me + o(s) = mo(s)


me + a(s) = ma(s)


te + o(s) = to(s)


te + a(s) = ta(s)


lhe + o(s) = lho(s)


lhe + a(s) = lha(s)


nos + o(s) = no-lo(s)


nos + a(s) = no-la(s)


vos + o(s) = vo-lo(s)


vos + a(s) = vo-la(s).

Não são tão comuns hoje em dia como foram outrora, mas são interessantes!

Dois pronomes também podem vir separados, como no caso de "Não se lhes [diabéticos] dá comida com açúcar". Aliás creio que no Brasil 'lho' seja considerado incorrecto, enquanto que em Portugal aceito; não sei da África, deve seguir a norma de Portugal. Não consegui encontrar fontes para esse assunto, mas esta conversa com chatgpt talvez tenha dicas https://chatgpt.com/share/673a8c69-cecc-800c-9124-73587be45271

Acho que não precisa contraí-las. Acho que Ele o lhe disse estaria correto também, e é até algo que eu diria.

@Schilive Que interessante! Vocês teriam alguma referência (por exemplo, a alguma gramática) onde houvesse um maior nível de detalhes? Também gostaria de saber um pouco mais sobre seu uso no português brasileiro, já que foi citado como uma possível exceção

https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/pronominalizacao-e-contraccao-de-pronomes/28391 Eis uma tabela. Não se usa em português brasileiro formas como: Ele mo disse. Se diz: ele me disse isso. Seria interessante que um falante português nos indica quais são as que continuam sendo utilizadas.

@Gauss, as regras de pronomes átonos em português são bem mais abrangentes do que em Portugal, notando que seu uso é mais formal e menos natural; em Portugal, usa-se ênclise primeiro e próclise quando impossível a ênclise. No Brasil, quando não há uma regra obrigando ênclise ou próclise (ou mesóclise), usa-se qualquer um. Porém, pode ver "se lhe" na Constituição Brasileira e algumas ~regras~ no CiberDúvidas.

Seria interressante se um falante português nos indicasse*, não "que nos indica". Ademais, essas formas contraídas não são usadas coloquialmente em lugar algum, pertencem à via culta, e desse modo existem e se usam sim no português brasileiro.
Só imagino quem contrata esses serviços de tradução...

Não, no Brasil, não se usam. Que ideia. Talvez em algumas redações. Na fala NUNCA. "Seria interressante"... [sic] E sim, indicasse. Certo.

@Quaestoria, acho que "lho" e "so" pode acontecer naturalmente como "lh'o" e "s'o", menos como abreviações e mais como acidentes. Porém, acho que o português Jacinto já disse que onde nasceu, usava... Talvez eu encontrei onde ele disse isto. Meio que achei [https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/9130/tomar-no-lo-%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-tecnicamente-poss%c3%advel-na-l%c3%adngua-portuguesa].

"Na fala NUNCA". Não importa. Se algo é oral ou escrito pouco importa para o registro. Mo/to/lho não são usados coloquialmente em lugar nenhum.
