# verb + -o and verb + -lo

Tags: gramática, português-europeu, verbos

Why

> Estou triste de sentir, e reflito-o à janela ao som da água que pinga e da chuva que cai

is it `reflito-o` and not `reflito-lo`?

What's  a rule that's about `verb + -o` and `verb + -lo` called? I haven't even been able to find oen.

Comment: The pronoun, in this case *o*, can be either before or after the verb. When it is after, it joins with the verb, as "mato-o" and "amo-o". If the verb ends in *-r*, *-s* or *-z*, then *lo* is joined instead: "para matá-lo", "tu faze-lo" and "nós fazemo-lo". When the verb ends in a nasal vowel, then *no* is joined: "eles são-no" and "para fazerem-no". In Brazil, *lo* for verbs ending in *-s* and specially *-z* sounds weirds; I think the situation in Portugal is complicated.

Comment: Also, the origin of the "rule" is that in the olden days, before even 1200's, people only used *lo* (*la*, *los*, *las*), so "amo-lo", "matar-lo", "gostam-lo". Some consonants betweens two vowels ceased to be pronounced, turning "amo-lo" into "amo-o". In the case of "matar-lo", as *r* and *l* are very similar, then *l* only was said; turning "matar-lo" into "matá-lo". With "gostam-lo", the *l* got nasaled, and as the greatest difference between *l* and *n* is that the second is nasal, *l* turned into *n*, turning *gostam-lo* into *gostam-no*.

Comment: @Schilive Please turn your comments into an answer!

Comment: @Schilive `...with "gostam-lo"` --> why then not `"gostam-no"`? Or did you mean that it *used to be* `L` but then it'd become  `N` and so is nowadays?

Comment: @DankenN, yeah. It used to be that people said *gostam-lo*, but then it became *gostam-no*. This happened because the *l* got nasalized.

Comment: @stafusa, I really thought this question had been answered somewhere. It seems like a very fundamental question for a Portuguese learner. But I find really difficult to find questions in the search bar, so I was hoping someone had it in their meaty database.

Comment: Bom ponto, @Schilive. Talvez [essa resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/3585/2764) seja relevante, mas penso que não completa, e sem seus comentários históricos, que são bem interessantes.

Comment: @Schilive I think no, na, etc used to be used after nasal vowels, not only in the enclictic position. So "não no vi" instead of "não o vi"

Comment: @Schilive similarly, would it be correct to say: `amo-lhe (a ela, a voce)`, `amo-te (a ti)` ?

Comment: @Artefacto, yup. I think Camões wrote something like that in Os Lusíadas. That was also the case for *-s/z* + *-o*, as *poi-la* ([link](http://www.cantigasdesantamaria.com/csm/5)). And even as article, as in *depois-lo* (same link).

Comment: @DankenN _amar_ takes a direct object, so _amo-a_, _amo-o_. _amo-lhe_ is only possible if _lhe_ is non-argumental like _amo-lhe o humor_ (=I love his/her humor).

Comment: @Artefacto what do you mean? `Eu amo-te` would be incorrect? How then would one say `eu te amo` using the postfix notation?

Comment: @DankenN _amo-te_ is correct, because _te_ is both dative/accusative. But in the 3rd person we have o/a/os/as for the accusative case and lhe/lhes for the dative.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is simple: the pronoun is *-lo(s)*/*-la(s)* if the verbal form ends with a consonant such as r, s, z. If the verb ends with a nasal sound, it will be *-no(s)*/*-na(s)*. Elsewhere it will be *-o(s)*/*-a(s)*.

It is that simple, it happens for historical reasons during the development of the language!

Comment: There is one exception tough: "ele quer" -> "ele quere-o"