# dizer-lho -- correct?

Tags: gramática, português-europeu, verbos

I've just found this

> E olhe, não sei se me fica mal dizer-lho, mas a rapariga quer-lhe deveras, João
> Eduardo.

in a portuguese book.

However, this topic [verb + -o and verb + -lo](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/9756/verb-o-and-verb-lo) claims that `verb-ar /verb-er` + `lo` ==> `verb-a / verb-e-lo`. Namely, the `r` gets eliminated off a verb when a verb ends, among `z` and `s`, in `r`.

t
So, is this `dizer-lho` correct or not? What's a rule here then?

I'm asking about the Portuguese of Portugal only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final *r* (or *s*/*z*) are dropped only when appending *-o/a/os/as* or when appending *-nos* after the 1st person plural.

The only exception is *quer+o* ⇒ *quere-o* (*qué-lo* is not really used that much).

Comment: `The final r (or s/z) are dropped only when appending -o/a/os/as` --> you then claim that these are correct: `dize-o`, `senti-o`, `faze-o`, `grita-as`?

Comment: The 1st sentence of your  answer claims that there's

Comment: @Camila326 it doesn't. There is no "dize" so there is no "dize-o". There is however "dizer" and "dizes" so there is "dizê-lo" and "dize-lo"

Comment: There's not. But you've said `only`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct, `lho` is a contraction `lhe(s) + o` (indirect object + direct object). Thus `dizer-lho` means `dizê-lo a ele(s)/ela(s)/você(s)`.

No alteration occurs when the verb and `lho` are concatenated (and thus `dizer-lho` is correct, in all dialects). Alterations occur only in the following cases:

- ...r/s/z + o(a)(s) → ...(delete final consonant)-lo(a)(s), and some short verbs admit two possibilities (e.g., qué-lo/quere-o [1]);
- ...N + o(a)(s) → ...N-no(a)(s) where N is a nasal sound (-m or -õe, or -ão?);
- ...mos + nos → ...mo-nos (where nos is 1st person plural [2]).

List of contractions indirect + direct object:

- me → ma(s), mo(s);
- te → ta(s), to(s);
- lhe(s) → lha(s), lho(s);
- nos → no-lo(s), no-la(s);
- vos → vo-lo(s), vo-la(s).

More examples: https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/3585/13298 (in Portuguese).

[1]. "Quere-o" - https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/quere-o/2147

[2]. "Lavamo-nos e Lavamos-vos" - https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/lavamo-nos-e-lavamos-vos/31030

Comment: I know what it is and how it's created. My question is whether or not it's correct to attach it after `verb-r`. If it is, why isn't it correct to use, let's say, `prepara(r)-lo` with `r` too? Which isn't the same, but similar.