# Duvida entre "capaz de..." "...as identificar" ou "...identifica-las"

Tags: ortografia, concordância, crase

Inicialmente eu iria escrever "identifica-las", mas o google docs apontou como erro e não achei na minha [colinha](https://www.conjugacao.com.br/verbo-identificar/) esse termo, então agora estou me perguntando se existe esse tipo de construção no portugues ou tirei do além isso.

Caso "capaz de as identificar" seja o correto, também estou em duvida se tem crase no "as" ou não.

Comment: Janilson, tenho a certeza que já há uma pergunta com boas respostas sobre isto. Enquanto não a encontro, fica aqui a resposta, que é bem simples. "Capaz de as identificar" = "capaz de identific**á**-las" (o r de identifica**r** cai, e põe-se acento, porque esse **a** é tónico). "Tu as identificas" = "tu identifica-las" (o s de "identifica**s**" cai, o **a** não leva acento porque é átono).

Comment: Encontrei a [tal pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/99/quando-acentuar-verbos-com-pronomes-encl%c3%adticos/267#267), onde já tens resposta à tua. Tenho a impressão que há outra com resposta mais completa, mas não consigo encontrar.

Comment: Reparei agora que tem perguntas acerca da crase. Novamente também já há pergunta sobre isso. Vou tentar encontrar. Mas neste caso basta lembrar que "à" é feminino de "ao", e "a" de "o"; não se diz "capaz de aos identificar", portanto também não é "de às identificar", é "capaz de os/as identificar".